# How to get read working again after while loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, read

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Export Tape(s):"
echo "---------------"

stdbuf -oL echo "list media" | bconsole | {

while IFS= read -r line
do
        line=$(echo ${line^^})

        if [[ "$line" == *"POOL"* ]] && [[ "$line" != *"DEFAULT"* ]] && [[ "$line" != *"FILE"* ]] && [[ "$line" != *"SCRATCH"* ]] && [[ "$line" != *"DUMMY"* ]]; then
                echo " "
                echo "$line" | awk '{print "["$2"]"}'
        fi

        
        if [[ "$line" == *"FULL"* ]]; then
                inChanger=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $20}')

                if [[ "$inChanger" == 1 ]]; then
                        expiresIn=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $31}')

                                if [[ "$expiresIn" != 0 ]]; then
                                         echo "$line" | awk '{print "   Date: "$28" Barcode: "$4}'
                                        ((tapesToExport++))
                                fi

                else
                        newElement1=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}')

                                if [[ $newElement1 != VOL* ]] && [[ $expiresIn = 0 ]]; then
                                        newElement2=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $28}')
                                        tapeBarcode+=( $newElement1 )
                                        tapeDate+=( $(date -d "$newElement2" +"%s") )
                                fi
                fi
        fi
done

IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort <<<"${tapeDate[*]}"))
unset IFS

sorted=( "${sorted[@]:0:$tapesToExport}" )

count=-1
for (( i=0; i<"${#tapeDate[@]}"; i++ )); do
        (( count++ ))

        if [[ "${sorted[$i]}" = "${tapeDate[$count]}" ]]; then
                arrayOfRequiredIndexes[$i]=$count
        else
                (( i-- ))
        fi

        if [[ "$i" = "$((tapesToExport-1))" ]]; then
                break
        fi

done

        if [[ "$tapesToExport" > 0 ]]; then
                echo " "
                echo -e "\e[1;37m╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕\e[0m"
                echo -e "\e[1;37m│       Populate the TAPES.XLS file with the tapes above.       │\e[0m"
                echo -e "\e[1;37m│           Print EXCEL file and attach to each tape.           │\e[0m"
                echo -e "\e[1;37m│                                                               │\e[0m"
                echo -e "\e[1;37m│         Replace the "$tapesToExport" tape(s) that you'll export above        │\e[0m"
                echo -e "\e[1;37m│                 with the "$tapesToExport" recommended below...               │\e[0m"
                echo -e "\e[1;37m╘═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╛\e[0m"
                echo " "
                echo "Recommended Tapes to Import:"
                echo "----------------------------"

                for i in ${arrayOfRequiredIndexes[@]}; do
                        echo "Date: "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d @${tapeDate[$i]})" Barcode: "${tapeBarcode[$i]}
                done
        else
                echo " "
                echo -e "\e[1;37mThere are no tapes to export.\e[0m"
                echo " "
                exit 1
        fi
}
                if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
                    exit 0
                fi

                echo " "
                echo "When you are finished importing the tape(s),"
                echo "Type 'rescan' to issue a command for the tape"
                echo "library to rescan.  Or you can type 'exit' to"
                echo "terminate the program."

                while [[ "${userResponse}" != "exit" ]]; do
                        read -p "[rescan]/exit: " userResponse
                             if [[ "$userResponse" == "rescan" ]] || [[ -z "$userResponse" ]]; then
                                echo "update slots storage=TL2000-01 drive=0"
                             fi
                done

                                echo " "
                                echo -e "\e[2;37mDone!\e[0m"
                                echo " "
```

I've edited the post and put all the code so that there's full context. `bconsole` is a binary executable that I'm calling and the `list media` command does a dump of data to the stdout that I'm parsing with awk line-by-line.

The problem is that the very last `read` statement isn't taking input from the user.  I will get prompted with `"[rescan]/exit: "` and I have the ability to type, but when I press  it just asks for input yet again without the `"[rescan]/exit: "` prompt. There are no errors whatsoever. I have to CTRL-C out of the script to terminate it because it gets stuck (I'm assuming) on the last `read` statement. I've read all about how stdin is redirected and can't be leveraged by read until the program is complete, however my `while loop` is complete and none of the solutions or fixes seem to circumvent my problem.

I've tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403794/bash-script-user-input-read-is-not-working-properly) and about four others and neither of them are getting me closer to getting the last `read` statement accepting input from a user.

I'm under the assumption that `read` is somehow still redirected with the while loop, but I thought that it would release once the loop is done.  What would the silver bullet be to get this to work?

Comment: Please include what you mean by "isn't working". Also, what is `bconsole`? It doesn't seem to be a standard tool.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more concise.

Comment: You post is still not verbose enough, what errors do you face ? what output are you getting on the screen ? are you sure it is related with the read and not how the  while loop is programmed ?

Comment: @JustKhaithang edited again for more verbosity.  I really don't know.  I tried moving the while loop around, it didn't help.  I have a strange feeling it has something to do with the 

```stdbuf -oL echo "list media" | bconsole | {
....
}```

section and placement or something.

Comment: The pipe is using stdin of the process in `{ ... }`, this is why the user input is not detected by the `read`. This is not the way bash works. To answer the question, it would be a complete refactoring of the script.